# Can I include only some aspect in the coverage report of Jest/Enzyme

Tags: jestjs, enzyme

I am using the Jest coverage report after my tests are run to check the coverage of my code. Although in this, I have the 4 values 
1. Statements 
2. Branches 
3. Functions
4. Lines

Is there any way I can display only the statements and not the other 3 properties in the coverage report or is it always autogenerated with all 4 properties?

If there is a way, how do I do that?